# How can I get the Value of a DataGridViewCell from the Cell_Leave event?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, int

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex > 1)
    {
        int cellValue = Convert.ToInt32(((DataGridViewCell)sender).Value);

        if (cellValue < 20)
        {
            ((DataGridViewCell)sender).Value = 21;
        }   
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the value of the cell that the event fired from.

An exception is fired when I try to cast `sender` to a `DataGridViewCell`:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' to
>   type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell'.

What do you recommend I do?

I need to check if the value is less than 20, and if it is, bump it up to 21.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try working with `theDataGrid[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex].Value`.  I'd expect that the sender is more likely to be the DataGridView object rather than the cell itself.

Answer (score 4):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value != null)
            {
                int cellmarks = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
                if (cellmarks < 32)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = "Fail";
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = "Pass";
                }

            }
        }
```

This code will get currentcell value.may this help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value of the cell as

```
dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].FormattedValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

sender's type is DataGridView, so you may use the following line:

```
int cellValue = Convert.ToInt32(((DataGridView)sender).SelectedCells[0].Value);
```

Comment: This is a very good answer because one would sometimes create a generic event handler. That is; the event handler is meant to service several DataGridViews. Dulini Atapattu did the trick here by querying the sender parameter as a DataGridView object.

Answer (score 0):

I did a slight variant for a _CellClick event.

```
private void Standard_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
     {
        int intHeaderId = 0;
        switch (((DataGridView)sender).Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
        {
           case "grcHeaderId":
              intHeaderId = (int)grvEnteredRecords[grcHeaderId.Index, e.RowIndex].Value;
              break;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting the value of the cell using the EditedFormattedValue property, since in my testing the FormattedValue that I have entered is always null.